# What is the name of this type of layout?

Tags: android

I want to know if this type of layout have a specific name, Im guessing  it is some kind of gridLayout combined with another Layout?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I cannot comment on your post due to my current rep level I will have to write an answer...

I believe you may be wanting a CardView. Please see the following link on how to use this ViewGroup: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-card-view-edb905e67cd6

Answer (score 0):

It is a combination of cardview and  grid layout. You can also use cardview in listview item or recycler view.